# Laravel Voyager / S3 Storage - can't retrieve avatar

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, voyager

I have set my laravel/voyager so that It will upload the user avatar to S3.
Uploading was successful but user avatar is broken. I got 403. What is wrong ?

**config/voyager.php**

```
storage' => [
  'disk' => 's3',
],
```

**config/filesystems.php**

```
's3' => [
   'driver' => 's3',
   'key' => env('S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
   'secret' => env('S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
   'region' => env('REGION'),
   'bucket' => env('BUCKET')
],
```

**.env**

```
S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID=accesskeyid
S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=accesskey
BUCKET=bucket
REGION=region
```

Comment: What is your image path in database ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your S3 bucket is publicly accessible. Otherwise you will not be able to view the image without a token.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need to do when you're trying to upload a new image, is to set the visibility to public, otherwise you get 503.

```
Storage::disk('s3')->setVisibility($image,'public');
```

And if the image or folder already exists, you need to change the visibility in the S3 console to public.

Or an alternative is to set the visibility in the **config/filesystems.php** file to public

```
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'visibility' => 'public'
        ],
```

Hope this can help anybody.